# Plot xy slices for different z positions

Tags: c++

As the title says, I am doing some analysis of some microscopical structure. I am trying to find the focus using a laser, so I am taking a XY scan of the structure at various increasing Z positions from the laser. 
After the scan is done, I might have some few hundred up to few thousand of such slices. 
I would like to see the "evolution" of this structure, so I need to see how the slices look like at all the positions and find "the best slice" that fits my criteria (whatever that might be, and will be decided by looking at the slices, not through code).

The program I am plotting everything in is CERN's ROOT Analysis framework, which is basically C++. I can plot on one page a maximum of 24 such slices (4 columns, 6 rows of such pictures) given the dimensions I input for a plot (I want one image to have a minimum of pixels in X and Y as to still be distinguishable). Ok, now that the maximum number of plots on one page is 24, it can still be less than that since I can see them good, but not more than that, as the plots become indistinguishable.

What is the best way to plot such a thing? I am still struggling to find if it is better to plot separate plots into a folder and make a gif out of them, or put 24 times how many I have in total, but that would mean editing a for loop for the z's and it seems not the best idea. What would a good solution be?

Comment: Put all the slices as individual files in a folder with names in order by Z depth.  View them with a tool such as IrfanView that lets you scroll back and forth through the images.  Why screw around with multiple images on a page?  The point you want will always be at a page break (based on Murphy's Law).

Comment: Heh, most surely will be there. Luck is never in one's favor. Especially when doing Physics.